# Prolog: Variable with multiple values

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to implement a program that takes a variable with multiple values and evaluates all the values. For instance:

```
foo(X,R) :-
  X > 2,
  Z is R + 1,
  R = Z.
```

This program might not be valid, but it will help me ask the question regardless.

My question: If `X` has multiple values, how would I increment the counter for each value `X > 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to instantiate `X` to increasingly larger integers you can use the following:

```
?- between(0, inf, X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
<ETC.>
```

PS1: Notice that you have to instantiate `R` as well since it is used in the arithmetic expression `Z is R + 1`.

PS2: Notice that your program fails for all instantiations of `X` and `R` since `R =\= R + 1` for finite `R`. The for instance means that the following query will not terminate:

```
?- between(0, inf, X), foo(X, 1).
```

---

Alternatively, the program can be rewritten in library [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) (created by Markus Triska):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

foo(X,R):-
  X #> 2,
  Z #= R + 1,
  R #= Z.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My question was more centered on if I have a variable with multiple values, would prolog evaluate every value and increment the counter for every value where X > 2?

Comment: @user2962883 Ah, I see. I have added an alternative solution to my answer which shows the same program in CLP(FD) where you can can express that a variable belongs to a certain range (e.g., `X #> 2` means that `X` is one of `[2,+inf)`).